# goMap / Jquery - stopping status check from getting blank response before Google map completes Geocode check

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I've been adding some custom functions to the GoMap Google Map library, but have run across a problem where I want to check if an address is valid but my external function keeps running without waiting for the actual response.

Inside the GoMap code I have created this function:

```
checkAddressExists: function(options){

        address = options.address;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              return true;  
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            });
```

This function works as it should and returns true or false.

However, in my external Javascript files, if I do something like:

```
var foo = $.goMap.checkAddressExists({address: address});
```

Foo remains undefined i.e it isn't waiting for the response before deciding whether it's true or false.

I have tried this but get nothing returned:

```
$.goMap.checkAddressExists({address: address}, function(response){
    alert(response);
});
```

Is there a way of making it pause to wait for the correct response from the library - or is it just that the GoMap library is not set up to provide a response?

I understand this may be a GoMap specific question, but just in case I'm missing a basic Jquery concept it's worth asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

AJAX is asynchronous and will not wait for the server to reply.
It is not possible to wait for the server to reply without freezing the browser.

jQuery 1.5's [Deferred Objects](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) can make this easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks - I figured it was something like that. I ended up writing a custom handler in GoMap that is fired by the success / fail returned from Google. This can then fire a function. Not as elegant as the main script waiting for a response, but gets the job done and while I'm hacking the plugin anyways.....